# Display results which have no count/zero as well

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a count of the number of logins during a given timeframe, currently my SQL query displays only results that had at least one login, I'd like it to display even those which have zero logins.

Query i'm using:

```
SELECT c.FullName, COUNT(l.Id) 
FROM LoginsTable l JOIN UsersTable u ON u.Email = l.Email JOIN Organisations c ON c.Id = u.OrganisationId 
WHERE l.AttemptTime > "2019-10-01" AND l.AttemptTime < "2019-11-01" AND l.Success = 1 
GROUP BY c.Name
ORDER BY c.Name ASC;
```

Comment: Try using `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: For both joins? I tried LEFT JOIN and it still doesn't display all the results

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. And take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues. Firstly, you either need to use a `RIGHT JOIN` from `LoginsTable` or reorder the `JOIN`s to put the `JOIN` to `LoginsTable` last and use a `LEFT JOIN`. Given the nature of your query the latter probably makes more sense.
Secondly, you need to put any conditions on fields from a table which has been `LEFT JOIN`ed into the join condition, otherwise MySQL converts the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html)). Finally, you should `GROUP BY` the same fields as specified in your `SELECT`. This should work:

```
SELECT c.FullName, COUNT(l.Id) 
FROM Organisations c
JOIN UsersTable u ON u.OrganisationId = c.Id
LEFT JOIN LoginsTable l ON u.Email = l.Email AND l.AttemptTime > "2019-10-01" AND l.AttemptTime < "2019-11-01" AND l.Success = 1 
GROUP BY c.FullName
ORDER BY c.FullName
```

Comment: Just to note, when I run this it returns 208 results when I expected 226, however that is more than the original 78 it was returning

Comment: @user2320010 it ought to return the number of organisations you have, unless there are some organisations that have no users. If that is the case, change the `JOIN UsersTable` to `LEFT JOIN UsersTable` and you should get the expected result.

Comment: Ah, two left joins sorted it

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 issues here:

> 1. your group by column is not listed on your column
> 2. date condition is using double quotes.

**try below query.**

```
SELECT c.FullName, COUNT(l.Id) 
FROM LoginsTable l 
LEFT JOIN UsersTable u ON u.Email = l.Email 
LEFT JOIN Organisations c ON c.Id = u.OrganisationId 
WHERE l.AttemptTime between '2019-10-01' AND '2019-11-01' AND l.Success = 1 
GROUP BY c.FullName
ORDER BY c.FullName ASC;
```

Comment: Tried this, it is still omitting those with zero count

Answer (score 0):

As Roman Hocke said you need to use left join as below :

```
SELECT c.FullName, COUNT(l.Id) 
FROM UsersTable u
JOIN Organisations c ON c.Id = u.OrganisationId 
LEFT JOIN LoginsTable l ON u.Email = l.Email 
WHERE l.AttemptTime > "2019-10-01" AND l.AttemptTime < "2019-11-01" AND l.Success = 1 
GROUP BY c.Name
ORDER BY c.Name ASC;
```

Moreover, you should fix your group by or select using the same field : SELECT c.Name or GROUP BY c.FullName ORDER BY c.FullName

EDIT : Nick's answer is the one. As he said perfectly well, you need to put your conditions in the on clause of your left join.

```
SELECT c.FullName, COUNT(l.Id) 
FROM UsersTable u
JOIN Organisations c ON c.Id = u.OrganisationId 
LEFT JOIN LoginsTable l ON (u.Email = l.Email AND l.AttemptTime > "2019-10-01" AND l.AttemptTime < "2019-11-01" AND l.Success = 1)
GROUP BY c.FullName
ORDER BY c.FullName ASC;
```